# ngFor don`t show all items immediately after place_changed event from google place autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, google-places-api

I need to add result to the list after place_changed event. I display the list below the input in which I find locations. Event works and result is pushed to array items. But the problem is that new added item don`t display immediately. It displayed after some time or when I click on form where this input is displayed.

.ts:

```
  @ViewChild('locationInput', { static: true }) input: ElementRef;
  autocomplete;
  items = [];
 ngOnInit() {
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.input.nativeElement, this.localityOptions);
    this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
      this.addToListSelectedItem();
    });
  }

  public addToListSelectedItem() {
    if (this.input.nativeElement.value) {
      this.items.push(this.input.nativeElement.value);
      this.input.nativeElement.value = '';
    }
  }
```

.html:

```
 <input
      #locationInput
      class="shadow-none form-control"
      formControlName="locality"
      placeholder=""
      [attr.disabled]="locationForm.controls['region'].dirty ? null : true"
    />
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let index = index">
      <div class="listOfLocation">
        <div class="itemList">{{ item }}</div>
        <img [src]="icons.cross" class="delete-button-img" alt="edit-icon" (click)="deleteTask(index)" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your component Change Detection Strategy is OnPush or google autocomplete is running outside zone.js:

```
 changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
```

And since items is array and it is stored in memory by reference you need to run manually change detenction:

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef)

public addToListSelectedItem() {
  ...
  this.input.nativeElement.value = '';
  this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better would be to work with an RxJS Subject, an Observable for items$ and use the async pipe. The async pipe works like magic what concerns updating the template :-)!

```
@ViewChild('locationInput', { static: true }) input: ElementRef;
autocomplete;
itemsSubject$ = new Subject<any[]>();   
items$ = this.itemsSubject$.asObservable();
// Use a separate array to hold the items locally:
existing = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.input.nativeElement, this.localityOptions);
    this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
      this.addToListSelectedItem();
    });
  }

public addToListSelectedItem() {
    if (this.input.nativeElement.value) {
       // Use spread syntax to create a new array with the input value pushed at the end:
       this.existing = [...this.existing, this.input.nativeElement.value];
       // Send the newly created array to the Subject (this will update the items$ Observable since it is derived from this Subject): 
       this.itemsSubject$.next(this.existing);
       this.input.nativeElement.value = '';
    }
  }

// I added the deleteTask implementation to show you how this works with the subject:
deleteTask(index: number) {
    // The Array "filter" function creates a new array; here it filters out the index that is equally to the given one:
    this.existing = this.existing.filter((x, i) => i !== index);
    this.itemsSubject$.next(this.existing);
  }
```

And in the template:

```html
<input
      #locationInput
      class="shadow-none form-control"
      formControlName="locality"
      placeholder=""
      [attr.disabled]="locationForm.controls['region'].dirty ? null : true"
    />
<!-- Only difference here is adding the async pipe and using the items$ Observable instead -->
<div *ngFor="let item of items$ | async; let index = index">
      <div class="listOfLocation">
        <div class="itemList">{{ item }}</div>
        <img [src]="icons.cross" class="delete-button-img" alt="edit-icon" (click)="deleteTask(index)" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

For a working example of the RxJS Subject in this concept, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dxfsoq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts.

Maybe beyond this question, but since you're using a reactive form, why not use this.locationForm.get('locality').setValue('...') to set the input instead of using a ViewChild for working with the input? More control this way then using the ViewChild.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem was in running google autocomplete outside zone.js. And it was very useful to read about RxJS Subject! Also thanks for the advice about using setValue. I will change my code a little). I also need ViewChild input for initialization autocomplete.